# useLazyQuery results into "Too many re-renders"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphene-django

I am trying to [Execute queries manually](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually) and followed, therefore, the official Apollo documentation. I don't see any difference between the documentation and my code, however, I always get the error "Too many re-renders."

```
const FEED_QUERY = gql`
  query contactAccessKey($accessKey: String!) {
    contactAccessKey(accessKey: $accessKey) {
      id
      contactInformation
      belongsTo {
        id
        username
        email
      }
    }
  }
`;

function AccessKeySeeEmergencyContact() {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState("");
  const [getContactInformation, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(FEED_QUERY);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;

  if (data && data.contactAccessKey) {
    setContact(data.contactAccessKey);
  }

  const accessKeyCode = "34a60667-80e3-4c97-9ded-15875d6507b1";

  return (
    <div>
      {contact && <div>{contact.contactInformation}</div>}
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          getContactInformation({ variables: { accessKey: accessKeyCode } })
        }
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AccessKeySeeEmergencyContact;
```

Comment: you are setting a state variable in `render`, move it to a `useEffect`

Comment: I just wonder why it works for the documentation or did I miss anything there?

Comment: It is not even necessary to set a state in the component, not sure what is going on there

Answer (score 1):

**useApolloClient** has functions that return a Promise and I have solved a similar issue by using this.
Please note I just copied and edited your code, there could be few syntax errors. All the best.

```
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

function AccessKeySeeEmergencyContact() {
    const [contact, setContact] = useState('');
    const client = useApolloClient(); // this gives an ApolloClient    

    const accessKeyCode = '34a60667-80e3-4c97-9ded-15875d6507b1';

    return (
        <div>
            {contact && <div>{contact.contactInformation}</div>}
            <button
                onClick={async () => {
                    const { data } = await client.query({
                        query: FEED_QUERY,
                        variables: { accessKey: accessKeyCode },
                    });
                    console.log(data);
                }}>
                Click me!
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AccessKeySeeEmergencyContact;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bad Apollo example!

```
const [contact, setContact] = useState("");
const [getContactInformation, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(FEED_QUERY);

if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;

// additional condition to avoid endless rerendering
if (!contact && data && data.contactAccessKey) {
  setContact(data.contactAccessKey);
}
```

**Using state is unnecessary** (even with condition forces additional rerendering) - you can read data directly from `data` (it's just a private variable):

```
return (
  <div>
    {data && <div>{data.contactInformation}</div>}
```

Comment: `if (!contact  ...  setContact` creates once running block fired on data load ... you can also use `onCompleted` handler ... or pass data to conditionally rendered subcomponent (convert/manipulate in child).

Comment: After how much render it is not optimized ? Because 1 render when mount, another when loading is set to false and another one when we fill data into state on completed

Comment: @HamzaKhattabi it's a kind of 'on completed', there is `onCompleted` handler you can use f.e. to convert received data (using state makes sense if it is costly, otherwise use conversion during render) - using it would be smarter than those conditions ... by using `data` directly you can have only 2 renders (for `useQuery`) and 3 for `useLazyQuery` - saving data in state always add next render and needs additional [conditions] code